# Python : Splitting a string by numbers, letters and -_

Tags: python, regex, string, split

Let's say that I have a string like this one

```
string = 'rename_file_1122--23-_12'
```

Is there a way to split this like that

```
parts = ['rename','_','file','_','1122','--','23','-_','12']
```

I tried with the regular expression but it does not work

```
import re

name_parts = re.findall('\d+|\D+|\w+|\W+', string)
```

The result was:

```
['rename_file_', '1122', '--', '23', '-_', '12']
```

########## Second part

If I have a string like this one :

```
string2 = 'Hello_-Marco5__-'
```

What are the conditions that I need to use to get  :`['Hello','_-','Marco','5','__-']`. My goal is to split a string y groups of letters,digits ans '-_'.

Thanks fors yours answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively you could use [**`groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from [**`itertools`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import groupby

string = 'rename_file_1122--23-_12'

result = [''.join(value) for key, value in groupby(string, key=str.isalnum)]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['rename', '_', 'file', '_', '1122', '--', '23', '-_', '12']
```

edit:

I came up with a perhaps simpler solution, using regular expressions:

```
string = 'rename_file_1122--23-_12'
result = re.split('([_-]*)', string)
print(result)
```

Same output.

[**`re.split`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) will split the string based upon matching the regular expression. The expression I've used includes a grouping pattern, and split includes the match in the result:

```
([_-]*)
```

Means match (and remember the result) of a sequence of one or more of any of `_` or `-`. `*` means one or more, `[]` means any of whatever's inside the square brackets.

Without the group, just using `[_-]*` we'd get the following, without the matches:

```
string = 'rename_file_1122--23-_12'
result = re.split('[_-]*', string)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['rename', 'file', '1122', '23', '12']
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
re.findall(r'[^\W_]+|[\W_]+', string)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v0kR2o/1).

**Regex details**:

- `[^\W_]+` - one or more chars other than non-word and `_` chars (so, one or more letters or digits)
- `|` - or
- `[\W_]+` - one or more non-word and/or `_` chars.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/B5g3MO):

```
import re
string = 'rename_file_1122--23-_12'
name_parts = re.findall(r'[^\W_]+|[\W_]+', string)
print(name_parts)
# => ['rename', '_', 'file', '_', '1122', '--', '23', '-_', '12']
```

Comment: I did a couple of double takes when I looked at this regex, because I thought 'wut? Match not-"something" or match "something"? That would match _everything_'. Which is exactly what it needs to do -- find either "not-something" or "something", and keep matching until it finds the opposite. Nice!

Comment: @PranavHosangadi This is a tokenization technique, when two separate opposite alternatives are used in a single pattern. They match all the text in the end, true, just splitting it into two types of tokens. There may be more alternatives, depending on token types.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution for the second part, it is the following :

```
name_parts=re.findall(r'[^\d_]+|[^\D]+|[^\W_]+|[\W_]+', string)
```

Comment: It's not great to edit the question with a second part. Makes our answers look incomplete or inept.